# How to nest a stream inside a stream in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I know this is question has been asked before but for some reason those solutions did not work for  me.

I have two streams nested in each other and every time I run the code ,It's showing this error , **RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.**

and this is my code.

```
class Green extends StatefulWidget {
  const Green({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Green> createState() => _GreenState();
}

class _GreenState extends State<Green> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("gates").snapshots(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error = ${snapshot.error}');
        
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) {
            final data = docs[i].data();
            return Second(g: data["gname"]);
          },
        );
          }
        
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
        ),);
  } 
}





// second
class Second extends StatefulWidget {
  String? g;

   Second({Key? key,required this.g}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Second> createState() => _SecondState();
}

class _SecondState extends State<Second> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 600,
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(uid)
            .where("gatename", isEqualTo: widget.g)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (_,   snapshot2) {
        if (snapshot2.hasData) {
        if (snapshot2.data?.size == 0) {
          return Center(child: Text('No Data'));
        } else {
          final ds = snapshot2.data!.docs;
          return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(38.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: ds.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, i) {
            final d = ds[i].data();
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(d["time"].toString()),
              leading: Text(d["gatename"].toString()),
            );
          },
        ),
          );
        }
        }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I believe it is a layout issue, I have tried using sizedbox,expanded widgets but..they are showing different errors.

Comment: How should this look like? Could you provide a sketch of the desired layout? First problem I see is that you have a flexible widget nested into another one (i.e. ListView nested into another ListView). I guess you can't have a scrollable list view in another scrollable ListView. You might want to try to wrap the inner ListView with an `Expanded` widget.

Comment: Hi, you mean Listview.builders causing the problem ryt.!?

Comment: Well, yes, I think so, but it's hard to tell because I don't see what the widget is supposed to look like. But generally, you cannot nest flexible widgets without Expanded or Flexible or something along those lines